# Parsing a text file

Tags: java, parsing, text-parsing

guys. I have a task and would like to hear your advice on implementation details.

I have a file which contains information about clients and their accounts.

FIRST_NAME=Joe
LAST_NAME=Bishop
RECEIPT.0.ID=123
RECEIPT.0.CURRENCY=USD
RECEIPT.1.ID=3654
RECEIPT.1.CURRENCY=EUR
.......................
CARD.0.TYPE=VISA
.......................

FIRST_NAME=Peter
LAST_NAME=Swalsky
...............

And so on. So I need parse this information into classes like Account etc. Shall I use Scanner class with certain match pattern and parse information step by step or there might be another elegant way to do that? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a valid Properties file, so `java.util.Properties` might help. It can load those files.

Comment: But as far as I know Properties is Hashtable and if I had two clients with two keys "FIRST_NAME", it wouldn't work. Am I right?

Comment: correct. Only works is the keys are unique. If not, Scanner is probably ok. You could also read the whole file into a String (if it is not too big) and do string.split("[=\n]"); then iterate over results as you see fit.